# Protractor: Stale element reference at "browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(confDial), FIFTY_SECONDS);"

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I am stuck at a point badly. I hit the stale element reference issue 7/10 times.
My application shows a conf dialog after operation is done. This msg appears for a second or so. I wanna read the text of the conf dialog.

```
var confDial= element(by.id('dialog'));
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(confDial), FIFTY_SECONDS);
confDial.getText().then(function(text1){
      expect(text1).toBe(TextExpected);
});
```

what I do is, I wait for the dialog to appear after the operation is done and then do a getText(). But it fails at the browser.wait() itself. The error is

> Failed: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page
>   document 09:14:52       (Session info: chrome=52.0.2743.116) 09:14:52 
>   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.21.371461
>   (633e689b520b25f3e264a2ede6b74ccc23cb636a),platform=Linux
>   4.2.0-42-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) 09:14:52     Command duration or timeout: 76
>   milliseconds 09:14:52     For documentation on this error, please
>   visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.html

How do I resole it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I know this will not solve your problem, but looks like your chrome and chrome driver versions are pretty old. It's always a good idea to upgrade to the latest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware of, the `visibilityOf(element)` requires presence.
Therefore you should first wait for the element to become present.

Try this:

```
browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(element(by.id('dialog'))), FIFTY_SECONDS);
var confDial= element(by.id('dialog'));
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(confDial), FIFTY_SECONDS);
//expect already resolves a promise, so no need for a then() here.
expect(confDial.getText()).toBe(TextExpected);

//confDial.getText().then(function(text1){
//      expect(text1).toBe(TextExpected);
//});
```

Evtl. also that way it could work (not sire though):

```
browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(var confDial = element(by.id('dialog'))), FIFTY_SECONDS);
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But no luck :(  Hit the same issue, same place

Comment: @jeet modified my answer to check presence before you define the object... does it work this way now?
If so, I usually just define the cssSelector-String in the variable and not the full element, to kind of follow the DRY principle.

Comment: Hey Ernst, Let me try this approach. Will post my observation. Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: @jeet I edited my answer a bit... maybe your `then()` is part of the error as the `expect()` statement itself already resolves the promise, so you don't need to have a `then()` before. Let me know, if it worked out for you.

Comment: I did follow this approach. And from past 4/5 runs I don't see the issue. Thanks a lot for helping me out. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Did you try isPresent?**

This will verify once object exists in DOM tree...

```
confDial.isPresent().then(function(result) {
    if ( result ) {
       confDial.getText().then(function(text1){
        expect(text1).toBe(TextExpected);
       });
    } 
    else {
   //some alternate action 
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes Vishal, I had tried it. 1st 2/3 runs, it worked. But later it started failing.